# Get name and value from option select in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using `foreach` to show the option from database, which has value like this:

```
<select name="location[]" data-placeholder="Search Location" multiple class="chosen-select">
   <?php foreach ($location as $key): ?>
     <option value=""></option>
     <option value="{{$key->id}}">{{$key->name}}</option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

I want to pass both the `{{$key->name}}` and `{{$key->id}}` to my controller to get a response like this `{'name':'city', 'id': '2'}`.

For now I'm only using the common way to pass the `{{$key->id}}` into controller using this method:

```
$loc = $request->location;
$i = 0;
foreach ($loc as $value) {

  if ($value == true) {
   $date_opt[] = [
     "id" => $value,
   ];
  }
  $i++;
}
return $date_opt;
```

But have no idea how to pass the `{{$key->name}}`.

Should I put the `{{$key->name}}` in another table or is there any possible way to do it?

Comment: `<option value="{{$key->id,$key->name}}">{{$key->name}}</option>` try this

Answer (score 2):

Its probably best in general practise **not** to send through this information and then save it based off the name provided through the select, but rather to just send the `id` and then have relationships which can pull through the name or/and store the name directly into that table by getting the relationship on the `POST` method and saving the name directly from the Database, if that makes sense.

But if you for some reason need to store the name in the request, here's a couple of ways it could be done.

You could look at using arrays to get somewhere but I'm not sure if that is what you're looking for

```
<option value="location[{{ $key->id }}][{{ $key->name }}]" />
```

I'd have to check but I'm not sure if you need to if you'll be able to do something like:

```
<option value="[{{ $key->id }}, {{ $key->name }}]" />
```

But not sure that'll come out in a very useable manner into your controller, another way to do this

```
<option value="{{ $key->id }}:{{ $key->name }}" />
```

Then in your controller exploding the value by the `:`, which would probably be easier in that instance.

```
$parts = explode(':', $value);
$id = $parts[0];
$name = $parts[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Place following in template :**

```
<select name="location[]" data-placeholder="Search Location" multiple class="chosen-select">
<?php foreach ($location as $key): ?>
   <option value=""></option>
   <option value="{{$key->name}},{{$key->id}}">{{$key->name}}</option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
```

**Place Following code in controller :**

```
$loc = $request->location;
$i = 0;
foreach ($loc as $value) {

   if ($value == true) {
     $data_arr = explode(',', $value);
     $date_opt[] = [
       "name" => $data_arr[0]
       "id" => $data_arr[1],
      ];
    }
   $i++;
  }
return $date_opt;
```

There are other ways to achieve but as per your provided code this is simple solution.

Comment: can you print_r($value); exit; and paste here?

Answer (score 0):

Send both data as value:

```
<option value="{{$key->id .'-'.$key->name }}">{{$key->name}}</option>
```

In controller do this

```
$location = explode("-", $request->input('location'));
```

Then $location[0] - holds ID, and $location[1] holds NAME